# Loading properties dynamically with Spring in Java

Tags: java, spring, properties

In my Java main, I have the following:

```
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);
```

SpringConfig.java looks something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"...", "..."})
@PropertySource("classpath:prod.properties")
public class SpringConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertiesResolver() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Configuration
    static class DatabaseConfig {

        @Value("${jdbc.url}")
        private String jdbcUrl;
        @Value("${jdbc.username}")
        private String jdbcUsername;
        @Value("${jdbc.password}")
        private String jdbcPassword;
        @Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}")
        private String jdbcDriverClassName;

        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
             DriverManagerDataSource source = new DriverManagerDataSource(jdbcUrl,  
                jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword);
             source.setDriverClassName(jdbcDriverClassName);
             return source;
        }
```

}

The issue is that I will want the person deploying the eventual JAR to specify all the DB properties, so I don't want to leave that properties file on the classpath.

What are my options for loading something at runtime and injecting it into the Spring context BEFORE it starts resolving all those Spring EL @Value fields?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your use case. Can you clarify `The issue is that I will want the person deploying the eventual JAR to specify all the DB properties, so I don't want to leave that properties file on the classpath.`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read a file outside of your classpath you can use the `file:` pseudourl instead of the `classpath:` pseudourl in your `PropertySource` annotation e.g.:

```
@PropertySource("file:/path/to/prod.properties")
```

This tells spring that the file [is to be loaded as a URL, from the filesystem](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#resources-implementations-filesystemresource); then you may swap the file according to your needs. If what you need is to load different files according to different environments what you may need is [profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition-profiles).

Profiles allow you to load beans according to the profile you used to start your application. What I do is to load a file according to the profile running using a replacement in my path:

```
@PropertySource("file:${user.home}/project/config.${spring.profiles.active:dev}.properties")
```

In this case I'm using a placeholder that will resolve the profile (and if no profile is active then it will load dev by default). For example, if the prod profile is active the file path will be resolved to this:

```
/home/eldermael/project/config.prod.properties
```

and if no profile was found then:

```
/home/eldermael/project/config.dev.properties
```

But this has a drawback that if you have several profiles, they all will be concatenated in the file path.

Comment: I wasn't quite sure how profiles are supposed to work since multiple profiles can be active at once (which would break the dynamic loading of the file). This is probably the most frustrating thing about spring framework as it doesnt support an easy approach to properties.